# Check if username already exists (PHP, PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a little problem, that's the 4th tutorial about username checking but they're all in depreciated MySQL and I would like to do it with PDO

here is my code:

```
$stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute(array($username));
if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {
$message='Username already taken';
} else { $message='User added'; }
```

As I understood, the "rowCount" is the equivalent of mysql_num_rows so I don't think there's a problem with that, the problem must be with the SQL Query, it shows me **"Username already taken" even if the username is not really taken**.

Where am I wrong please ?

Thanks

Comment: `rowCount()` only returns a valid count for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE queries. Instead, retrieve the result set with `$stmt->fetchAll()` and check the length of the resulting array.

Comment: check my answer, you are using wrong tool (function) to accomplish that!

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute(array($username));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (!empty($result) ) {
$message='Username already taken';
} else { $message='User added'; }
```

There are examples for a SELECT query [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

so you should use

```
 PDOStatement::fetchAll
```

which return an array of all results matching your query

Comment: You should explain why this works when the OPs code did not.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP Manual (which you should read before using a function or ask at SO):

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the
> last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding
> PDOStatement object.

Since your statement is SELECT, then its natural that you have unpredictable results

The same manual down the road have a best advice for your problem

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the
> number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. **Instead, use
> PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same
> predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use
> PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will
> be returned.** Your application can then perform the correct action.

Completely untested example that should give you idea of what the manual means

```
$stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT count(*) from users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute(array($username));
$norows = $result->fetchColumn(); 
if ( $norows  > 0 ) {
$message='Username already taken';
} else { $message='User added'; }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username');
$query->bindParam(':username', $username);
$query->execute();

if($query->rowCount() == 0){
   // do your insert
   return "Registered";
} else { 
  return "Username Taken";
}
```

Otherwise, check your MySQL table and see if the username is already there.